# Query to return winner and loser in the cups table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has this schema

```
year,team1,team2,winner
```

2010,12,13,12

I want to return data in this form

```
year,winner,runner-up
```

Can it be done using a sql query?

Comment: You could use a stored procedure for this.

Answer (score 2):

thinking out the box

> winner - winning team_id = 0
>       0 - the not winning team_id = -team_id

```
SELECT year, winner, ABS(winner - team1 - team2) AS `runner up`
FROM YourTable
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc1d1/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following query.  The meat-and-potatoes is the `CASE` statement, which, for each record in your original table, will choose the team which is *not* the winner as the runner-up.

```
SELECT year, winner, CASE WHEN team1 = winner THEN team2 ELSE team1 END AS runnerUp
FROM teamStats
```

Click the link below for a running example:

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c741/3)

Comment: You are missing `from` in your query

Comment: Could you please explain what query is doing?

Comment: @Dude : Already we know the winning team from the `winner` column. so the `runner-up` would be the other one. So we can use a case statement to return the team which not in the `winner` column..

Answer (score 0):

Just using a `CASE` expression.

Already we know the winning team from the `winner` column. so the `runner-up` would be the other one. So we can use a case statement to return the team which not in the `winner` column..

**Query**

```
SELECT `year`, winner,
    CASE winner WHEN team1 THEN team2 ELSE team1 END AS `runner-up`
FROM tblMatches;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21aeb/1)

Comment: I went ahead and tidied up your query, since it wasn't very pleasing to the eye ^ ^.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `VIEW` with `SELECT`, it will act as temp table form you and will return that table with required details.
`CREATE VIEW GET_WINNER as
SELECT year, winner, ABS(winner - team1 - team2) AS runner up
FROM YourTable`